# Call ASP.NET Web API from code-behind

Tags: asp.net, webforms, getjson, asp.net-web-api

How would I call an ASP.NET Web API directly from code-behind? Or should I be calling my javascript function that calls the getJSON method from code-behind?

I usually have something like:

```
    function createFile() {
        $.getJSON("api/file/createfile",
        function (data) { 
            $("#Result").append('Success!');
        });
    }
```

Any pointers appreciated. TIA.

*I'm using WebForms.

Comment: What do you mean by "code-behind"?

Comment: @SLaks Say I have an asp:button. On it's click event(server-side/code-behind), I'd like do a couple of stuff and then call my Web API action (createfile). Hope I'm clear.

Comment: Pls check my code example. Perhaps a bit naive and basic, but it is just for you 2 get the idea.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you must call the web service itself, you can try using `HttpClient` [as described by Henrik Neilsen](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Introduction-to-HttpClient-4a2d9cee).

[Updated HTTPClient Samples](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/08/26/list-of-asp-net-web-api-and-httpclient-samples/)

A basic example:

```
// Create an HttpClient instance 
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); 

// Send a request asynchronously continue when complete 
client.GetAsync(_address).ContinueWith( 
    (requestTask) => 
    { 
        // Get HTTP response from completed task. 
        HttpResponseMessage response = requestTask.Result; 

       // Check that response was successful or throw exception 
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); 

        // Read response asynchronously as JsonValue
        response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JsonArray>().ContinueWith( 
                    (readTask) => 
                    { 
                        var result = readTask.Result
                        //Do something with the result                   
                    }); 
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was trying to do. Sorry to e/o else for possibly not explaining well. Appreciate all your help.

Comment: When i try to convert this to vb.net requestTask.Result wont compile saying  "result is not a member of system.threading.tasks.task" but in c# its found in httpresponsemessage. is this property not in vb.net ? i used the telerek conversion site to do the conversion

Answer (score 6):

You should refactor the logic into a separate backend class and call it directly from youir code-behind and from the Web API action.

Comment: some sample code would help... I'm stuck on "call it directly from your code-behind" part- Usually I do it with my JS function.

Comment: @Becky: Call the separate class directly from your code-behind.

Answer (score 3):

Recommended in many software architecture books is that you shouldn't put any business logic in your (API)controller code. Assuming you implement it the right way, for instance that your Controller code currently accesses the business logic through a Service class or facade, my suggestion is that you reuse the same Service class/facade for that purpose, instead of going through the 'front door' (so by doing the JSON call from code behind)

For basic and naieve example:

```
public class MyController1: ApiController {

    public string CreateFile() {
        var appService = new AppService();
        var result = appService.CreateFile(); 
        return result;
    }

}

public class MyController2: ApiController {

   public string CreateFile() {
       var appService = new AppService();
       var result = appService.CreateFile(); 
       return result;
   }
}
```

AppService class encapsulates your business logic (and does live on another layer) and makes it easier for you to access your logic:

```
 public class AppService: IAppService {

     public string  MyBusinessLogic1Method() {
       ....
       return result;
     }
     public string  CreateFile() {

          using (var writer = new StreamWriter..blah die blah {
            .....
            return 'whatever result';
          }

     }

    ...
 }
```

Comment: I would argue that your usage of 'Correct' is incorrect.  There are certainly design paradigms that advocate this, just as there are others which say the whole controller/facade/etc path is a tremendous amount of wasted code/man hours.  I'm not going to downvote; however, I'm just saying that there are many definitions of 'Correct' for software design most of which are situationaly dependent.

Comment: True, my English is not perfect, 'Correct' wasn't the correct word.

Comment: Thanks for providing an example. I think I see what you're saying about the classes, though my question is on the actual method call of CreateFile() in the WebAPI. How should I be calling that from a server side event in a Web Forms application? What is the best approach?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you are using a WebAPI or a WebForm. In case of WebForm, you just do the same AppService call in your code behind (for instance inside an OnClick)