# how to call webapi function from codebehind in webforms

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webforms

I added a web api in my asp.net web forms project. I want to call this web api directly from my code behind. Both my code behind and web api are in the same project. Both are in same namespaces.

Is it the right way to instantiate the controller class and directly call the method in it(in webforms project - in button click). like:

```
SampleController obj = new SampleController();
Dictionary<String,String> values = obj.MyMethod();
```

Please suggest an alternative way, if this method is incorrect.

(This web-api is also consumed by another windows service using httpclient)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a problem you need help with?  Asking for opinions on the "right way" to do something is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call ASP.NET Web API from code-behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307286/call-asp-net-web-api-from-code-behind)